# Vertices that have a shared face in Python

Tags: scripting

Is this possible to write the script that can determine if certain vertices have a shared face?
For example, if 3 random vertices of a mesh connected with each other with a face.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bmesh to do that. BMesh offers facilities to navigate through verts/edges/faces.

So for instance:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.object

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh( obj.data )

bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

v1 = bm.verts[0]
v2 = bm.verts[1]
v3 = bm.verts[3]

inter = set( v1.link_faces ) & set( v2.link_faces ) & set( v3.link_faces )

print( inter )
```

`ensure_lookup_table` tells bmesh to prepare the data (you may want to use it too on `bm.edges` and `bm.faces`)

For more information, have a look to this [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html).